# How to return a double pointer from a C++ dll to C#?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, pinvoke, marshalling

I am trying to return a pointer from my C++ dll to C#. I tried everything, but my pointer of type double doesn't have a value.

Below is my import of the C++ dll:

```
[DllImport("/Resources/libfli.dll", EntryPoint = "FLIGetTemperature")]
public static extern unsafe int FLIGetTemperature(long dev, double* temperature);
// Get the temperature of a given camera. This function places the temperature of the CCD camera 
// cold finger of device dev in the location pointed to by temperature.
// Return Value: Zero on success. Non-zero on failure.
// Parameters: dev Camera device to get the temperature of.
// temperature Pointer to where the temperature will be placed.
// See Also: FLISetTemperature
```

the defination of FliGetTemperatre from the FLI_SDK_Documentation

```
LIBFLIAPI FLIGetTemperature (flidev_t dev, double* temperature)
Get the temperature of a given camera.
```

Below is how I declare my call to the .Dll in C#:

```
unsafe public void GetTheTemperatureOfTheCamera()
{
    int success=0;
    long ldev = 0;
    long* dev = &ldev;
    double lTemperature = 0;
    double* temperature = &lTemperature;
    success = FLIGetTemperature(ldev, temperature);
}
```

When I run my code I get the following error below:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in myApplication.exe
>
> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

I also tried marshaling and `IntPtr`, but that is not working either.

I have tried Fliopen that fucntion works. It success. Below is the code for FliOpen.

```
    [DllImport("/Resources/libfli.dll", EntryPoint = "FLIOpen")]
    public static extern unsafe int FLIOpen(long* dev, string name, long domain);

    unsafe public int InitDevice()
    {
        long ldev = 0;
        long* dev = &ldev;
        int success;
        string deviceName = "flipro0";// this is default name for device
        long domainName = 258; //this is default domain name

        success = FLIOpen(dev, deviceName, domainName);
        return success;
    }
```

The FLIOpen method is a success though

Comment: This doesn't look right.  A couple things to try...  First, do you have the typelib for the DLL, and can you find this method in oleview?  If so, please edit to post what oleview says about the method.  Second, I presume you have tried not using pointers on the C# side and simply using `FLIGetTemperature(long dev, ref double temperature)` as the `extern` definition?

Comment: The code is nonsense, very important that you first understand the api before you try to pinvoke it.  You *must* get FLIOpen() working first so you'll have a correct value for the 1st argument.

Comment: @HansPassant my Fliopen function works. I do have Api documentation and i have edited the post on how they structure their GetTemperature() function.

Comment: @Andrew I do not have the typelib for the DLL. I have tried using pointers in C# as you can see in the post, but i get the same error. Sorry i am not very familiar with managed/unmanaged code.

Comment: Does opening the DLL itself in oleview tell you anything? Some DLLs have the typelib embedded as a resource. There is very little chance that you need an explicit unsafe pointer to do pinvoke from C#.

Comment: Why on earth was this downvoted?

Comment: @Andrew opening the .DLL doesn't help me. I have the proper definition for the function written in C++. Currently, i am using a wrapper to access the .DLL function. I am not sure why i can't p/invoke the .DLL function directly.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the documentation, I would have wrote something like this :

```
unsafe public void GetTheTemperatureOfTheCamera()
{
     int success=0;
     long dev = 0;
     long* ldev  = &dev;
     success = FLIOpen(ldev, deviceName, domainName); //Get the device handle.

     if (success != 0)
        throw new Exception("Cannot open device");

     double lTemperature = 0;
     double* temperature = &lTemperature;
     success = FLIGetTemperature(dev, temperature);
}
```

Comment: ldev is not a pointer, It's a long with value 0. Look at my code above.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch between your C# `long` parameter and the unmanaged type `flidev_t`. The key point is that `long` is a 64 bit type. Assuming your code is running in Windows then `flidev_t`, which is an alias of C++ `long`, is 32 bits wide.

You also have no need for unsafe code here. You can declare the function like this:

```
[DllImport("/Resources/libfli.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int FLIGetTemperature(int dev, out double temperature);
```

I'm also assuming that the calling convention is `cdecl`, but you probably need to check the C++ header file to be sure about that.

You'll need to make other changes in your other p/invoke declarations. Essentially everywhere you have translated `flidev_t` to C# `long` you should change it to `int`. Or perhaps even `IntPtr`. Then you'd be one step ahead of the unmanaged code which currently is not fit for a 64 bit port I suspect!

Starting with `FLIOpen` that is going to be:

```
[DllImport("/Resources/libfli.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int FLIOpen(out int dev, string name, int domain);
```

Well, the domain parameter might be better translated as a C# enum with `int` base type.

Comment: I'll try that right now I don't have the camera. I'll try it when i get the camera from the manufacture.
Also, I have one more function for grabbing the frames which is declared as follow.
[DllImport("/Resources/libfli.dll", EntryPoint = "FLIGrabRow")]
public static extern unsafe int FLIGrabRow(long dev, void* buff, double width);
The defination of the method from manufacture is as follow.

Comment: // Grab a row of an image. This function grabs the next available row of the image from camera device dev. 
        // The row of width width is placed in the buffer pointed to by buff. 
        // The size of the buffer pointed to by buff must take into account the bit depth of the image, 
        // meaning the buffer size must be at least width bytes for an 8-bit image, and at least 2*width for a 16-bit image.
        // Return Value: Zero on success. Non-zero on failure.
        // Parameters: dev Camera whose image to grab the next available row from.

Comment: // buff Pointer to where the next available row will be placed.
Now i am confused in passing buff from C#, how would i pass buff, since it's a type void. If i want my image size to 2000 x 256, how would i have my declaration in C#

Comment: @Neo I don't particularly want to get into that detail. I'm reasonable confident that the 32/64 bit mismatch is the answer to the question that you asked.